# pandas calculating average for groups is resetting time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns Time and speed. I am trying to calculate the average speed for 10s intervals. The line of code below works,however, it resets the time to start from 00:00:00.

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10S', base=30, label='right')).mean()`

starting data frame

| index | speed |
| --- | --- |
| 14:01:01 | 1 |
| 14:01:02 | 1.2 |
| 14:01:03 | 1 |
| 14:01:04 | 1.2 |

and the outputted table is:

| index | speed |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 1.1 |

when the index value should have been 14:01:00 not 00:00:00

Comment: 1- which pandas version are you using? 2- please provide a DataFrame constructor for the example input (with the correct dtypes)

Comment: maybe add this to the parameters of the df.Grouper? offset='14h01min'

Comment: pd.Grouper() parameter base has been deprecated.  When I remove base, I get the groups starting with 14:01:01.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is to ensure the time column is set as an index so that you may use groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
Time,Speed
14:01:01,1
14:01:02,1.2
14:01:03,1
14:01:04,1.2
14:01:31,1.3
14:01:33,1.4
14:01:41,1.1
14:01:42,1.2
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

offset = 30  
df['seconds'] = (df.index.second - offset) % 60
df['group'] = (df.index - pd.to_timedelta(df['seconds'], unit='s'))

result = df.groupby('group')['Speed'].mean().reset_index()

result['group'] = result['group'] + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='s')
result.set_index('group', inplace=True)
result.index.name = 'Time'

print(result)
```

which gives you

```
                     Speed
Time                      
1900-01-01 14:01:00   1.10
1900-01-01 14:02:00   1.25
```

If you only want to retain the time (dropping the date), you can modify the code this way

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
Time,Speed
14:01:01,1
14:01:02,1.2
14:01:03,1
14:01:04,1.2
14:01:31,1.3
14:01:33,1.4
14:01:41,1.1
14:01:42,1.2
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

offset = 30  
df['seconds'] = (df.index.second - offset) % 60
df['group'] = (df.index - pd.to_timedelta(df['seconds'], unit='s'))

result = df.groupby('group')['Speed'].mean().reset_index()

result['group'] = result['group'] + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='s')

result['Time'] = result['group'].dt.time
result.drop('group', axis=1, inplace=True)
result.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

print(result)
```

which gives

```
          Speed
Time           
14:01:00   1.10
14:02:00   1.25
```